# Linking/Merging Facebook User and PFUser (Parse) in Swift

Tags: facebook, swift, authentication, parse-platform, linker

I am currently working on an application that allows the user to register and login via regular email and password. It also allows the user to login via Facebook. Both of these functionalities are working.

The problem is that - when a user registers via email and later tries to log in via facebook ( assuming he/she has the same email for facebook) the application treats him/her as a new user. A new record is created in the database.

I'm new to swift and parse. I tried to take the information that comes from facebook and get the user's email and compare it to the users already in parse....but then, how do I merge the two accounts? If you have successfully implemented this functionality I really would appreciated if you walked me through it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Show us some corresponding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Instead you would need to use [cloud code](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave) to intercept the new user before it's saved and check if the e-mail address is already associated with another account. If it is you can return an error from the cloud code and handle it in your app.

Comment: That makes sense. In this case we'd force the user to login via either facebook or email.  Would that deter the user experience? I've seen other apps that use a different piece of information to enforce users to only use a single account (e.g phone number)

Comment: I don't think its a problem for user experience. The alternate would be to always duplicate info across all user objects in the DB but that's a maintenance issue.